# how to use index in data dictionary?

Tags: vb.net, vb.net-2010

I am using a data dictionary in VB.NET windows application.

I am trying to get the data from dictionary using the for loop.

ex. I have below dictionary table and I want to get the values using the for loop.

> ```
> AAA - "0"   
> BBB - "0" 
> CCC - "0' 
> DDD - "0"
> ```

```
 For i As Integer = 0 To CatDictionaryNEW1.Count
' for each i I want to fetch the values using index of data dictionary
' when i = 0 then AAA should return
' when i =1 then BBB should return 
' and so on....
 next
```

How to do this ?

Comment: can you show how you declared the dictionary and how you add to it?

Answer (score 0):

you do not need to iterate the entire dictionary to test AAA or BBB (they are not Lists or Arrays):

```
 If CatDictionaryNEW1("AAA") = 0 Then
      do whatever
 End If

 If CatDictionaryNEW1("BBB") = 1 Then
      do whatever
 End If
```

You would need to walk thru the entire dictionary if you needed to find WHICH item or element contained a certain value:

```
  For each kvp as KeyValuePair in myDict
       if kvp.Value = MagicValue then
           Return kvp.Key
       End if
  Next
```